# How can I get all archive-URLs to use the same template?

Tags: templates, urls, archives

I notice that *mysite/?post_type=my_custom* are using index.php while *mysite/2018/?post_type=custom* are using archive.php. How can I get both of these requests to use the same template?

Btw: I'm using static page as homepage.

Comment: So your homepage is not an archive? That `post_type` parameter just adds an extra query variable. Is there a reason you aren't using custom post type archives?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't use `archive.php` because it isn't an archive

`example.com/?post_type=mycustom` is still the homepage, but with an additional query parameter

Instead, use the custom post type archive at `example.com/mycustom/`

Comment: Small side note, you can only use a custom archive, if archives is not set to false.